# how to save arrays of input into eloquent?

Tags: arrays, laravel, eloquent, laravel-collection

I am currently developing a project for event management with laravel 5, and im in the middle of obstacle right now. So now i am in the phase of creating tickets for events.

The relationship between the event model and ticket model is one to many. One event can have many tickets, and one tickets can only belong to one event.

Below is the view when people havent clicked the add ticket button:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeoRs.png)

and below is when people clicked the add ticket button:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEiNG.png)

for the fields, i name it in an array. below are the codes:

```
<input name="ticket[][name]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ticket Name">
<input name="ticket[][stock]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantity">
<input type="text" name="ticket[][price]" class="form-control">
```

So, the question is, how do i catch the data inputted in the controllers? and how to save it into the eloquent?

when i try to use dd($request->input('ticket')), it shows a list of arrays, not a collection.

im thinking of something like this:

```
foreach($request->ticket as $index => $ticket) {
        $event->tickets()->save(new Ticket($ticket));
    }
```

is it possible to do it like that? thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You have the right ideal here for most part. Ideally I would need a bit more information from you but I'll try my best to push you in the right direction. You'll definitely want to loop though the array of tickets and save each one individually.

Here is a lose example:

```
$tickets = Input::get('ticket');

foreach($tickets as $ticket){

   $newTicket = new Ticket; // create the new ticket
   $newTicket->name = $ticket['name']; // add name 
   $newTicket->stock = $ticket['stock']; // add qty
   $newTicket->price = $ticket['price']; // add price
   $newTicket->event_id = [you need an event id here];
   $newTicket->save(); // save the new ticket 

}
```

You can see above that you will also need to pass the event id associated with the ticket so that the relationship between the even and ticket can be linked together.

Comment: Im also thinking of looping through the array of tickets, but unfortunately when i try to dd($request->input('ticket'));, it shows not a collection of tickets, but it show list of arrays which contains the input fields. For example, if i try to add 2 tickets, when i try data dump the tickets inputs, it doesnt count as 2 tickets, but as 6 arrays of inputs, so array 1 is the name for ticket 1, array 2 the stock for ticket 1, array 3 for the price of ticket 1, array 4 for the name of ticket 2, and so on. Do you know how to make the arrays become collection which consist of 2 tickets? Thanks btw:)

Comment: why not change your input names like so to group them:
ticket[1][name]
ticket[1][stock]
ticket[1][price]
then:
ticket[2][name]
ticket[2][stock]
ticket[2][price]

and so on. By adding the key you can group them by input group